# CorePlot bar graph not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I have an implementation of CorePlot in my project and though I have no relevant errors or warnings in Xcode, have been unsuccessful in getting the plot to show up in the graph. The axis and chart show up fine, but no bars in the graph.

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

**Header File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PresentedViewControllerDelegate.h"
#import <CorePlot/ios/CorePlot.h>

@interface DeviceDetailModal : UIViewController     <PresentedViewControllerDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CPTPlotDataSource,CPTBarPlotDelegate>{
CPTGraph *graph;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PresentedViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *dataSet;

@property (nonatomic, strong) CPTBarPlot *aaplPlot;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation *priceAnnotation;

@end
```

**Main File**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DeviceDetailModal.h"
#import "DetailCell.h"
#import <CorePlot/ios/CorePlot.h>
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation DeviceDetailModal

NSString *  const CPDTickerSymbolAAPL = @"AAPL";

CGFloat const CPDBarWidth = 0.25f;
CGFloat const CPDBarInitialX = 0.25f;
@synthesize aaplPlot = aaplPlot_;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.03 green:0.06 blue:0.10 alpha:1.0]];

    UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(closeView)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton;

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    self.tableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    self.tableView.layer.borderWidth = 0.7;
    self.tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.tableView.opaque = NO;
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;

    self.dataSet = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    self.dataSet = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:571.70],
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:560.28],
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:610.00],
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:607.70],
              [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:603.00],
              nil];

    [self configureGraph];

    [graph reloadData];
}

-(void)configureGraph {

    CGRect hostingRect = CGRectMake(20, 350, 335, 310);

    CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:hostingRect];

    [self.view addSubview:hostingView];

    [hostingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.03 green:0.06 blue:0.10 alpha:1.0]];

    hostingView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
    hostingView.layer.borderWidth = 0.7;
    hostingView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:hostingView.bounds];

    hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

    [[graph defaultPlotSpace] setAllowsUserInteraction:TRUE];

    // 1 - Create the graph
    graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
    // 2 - Configure the graph
    //[graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainBlackTheme]];
    graph.paddingBottom = 30.0f;
    graph.paddingLeft  = 30.0f;
    graph.paddingTop    = -1.0f;
    graph.paddingRight  = -5.0f;
    // 3 - Set up styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
    // 4 - Set up title
    NSString *title = @"Portfolio Prices: April 23 - 27, 2012";
    graph.title = title;
    graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
    graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
    graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, -16.0f);
    // 5 - Set up plot space
    CGFloat xMin = 0.0f;
    CGFloat xMax = 7;
    CGFloat yMin = 0.0f;
    CGFloat yMax = 800.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price

    NSNumber *xAxisStart = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:xMin];
    NSNumber *xAxisLength = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:xMax];
    NSNumber *yAxisStart = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:yMin];
    NSNumber *yAxisLength = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:yMax];

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:xAxisStart length:xAxisLength];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:yAxisStart length:yAxisLength];

    // 1 - Set up the three plots
    self.aaplPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor redColor] horizontalBars:NO];
    self.aaplPlot.identifier = CPDTickerSymbolAAPL;
    // 2 - Set up line style
    CPTMutableLineStyle *barLineStyle = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
    barLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];
    barLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5;
    // 3 - Add plots to graph
    graph = hostingView.hostedGraph;
    CGFloat barX = CPDBarInitialX;
    NSArray *plots = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.aaplPlot, nil];
    for (CPTBarPlot *plot in plots) {
        plot.dataSource = self;
        plot.delegate = self;
        plot.barWidth = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:CPDBarWidth];
        plot.barOffset = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:barX];
        plot.lineStyle = barLineStyle;
        [graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
        barX += CPDBarWidth;
    }

    // 1 - Configure styles
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
    // 2 - Get the graph's axis set
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) hostingView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
    // 3 - Configure the x-axis
    axisSet.xAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    axisSet.xAxis.title = @"Days of Week (Mon - Fri)";
    axisSet.xAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    axisSet.xAxis.titleOffset = 10.0f;
    axisSet.xAxis.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    // 4 - Configure the y-axis
    axisSet.yAxis.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    axisSet.yAxis.title = @"Price";
    axisSet.yAxis.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    axisSet.yAxis.titleOffset = 5.0f;      
    axisSet.yAxis.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;

}

#pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
    return [self.dataSet count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    NSLog(@"DATA: %@",[self.dataSet objectAtIndex:index]);

    return [self.dataSet objectAtIndex:index];
}

#pragma mark - CPTBarPlotDelegate methods
-(void)barPlot:(CPTBarPlot *)plot barWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    // 1 - Is the plot hidden?
    if (plot.isHidden == YES) {
        return;
    }
    // 2 - Create style, if necessary
    static CPTMutableTextStyle *style = nil;
    if (!style) {
        style = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
        style.color= [CPTColor yellowColor];
        style.fontSize = 16.0f;
        style.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    }
    // 3 - Create annotation, if necessary
    NSNumber *price = [self numberForPlot:plot field:CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip recordIndex:index];
    if (!self.priceAnnotation) {
        NSNumber *x = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        NSNumber *y = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        NSArray *anchorPoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, nil];
        self.priceAnnotation = [[CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation alloc] initWithPlotSpace:plot.plotSpace anchorPlotPoint:anchorPoint];
    }
    // 4 - Create number formatter, if needed
    static NSNumberFormatter *formatter = nil;
    if (!formatter) {
        formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    }
    // 5 - Create text layer for annotation
    NSString *priceValue = [formatter stringFromNumber:price];
    CPTTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:priceValue style:style];
    self.priceAnnotation.contentLayer = textLayer;
    // 6 - Get plot index based on identifier
    NSInteger plotIndex = 0;
    if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] == YES) {
        plotIndex = 0;
    }
    // 7 - Get the anchor point for annotation
    CGFloat x = index + CPDBarInitialX + (plotIndex * CPDBarWidth);
    NSNumber *anchorX = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:x];
    CGFloat y = [price floatValue] + 40.0f;
    NSNumber *anchorY = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:y];
    self.priceAnnotation.anchorPlotPoint = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:anchorX, anchorY, nil]; 
    // 8 - Add the annotation 
    [plot.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea addAnnotation:self.priceAnnotation]; 
}


    @end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Plot ranges are given as a starting location and length. In your case, make the starting location the `min` value and the length `max - min`. Right now it's ok since the `min` is zero, but the length will be wrong if you ever change the `min` values.

The `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` datasource method must check the field parameter and return the correct value for the field. Return the `index` parameter value for the `CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation` field. Return the value from the `dataSet` array for the `CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip` field.

Comment: This is a non-answer. I appreciate the input, but this reads like documentation and does not answer the question. As is, the starting location and length should work (you confirmed this). Also I am returning valid data in the numberForPlot method. An appropriate answer would point to a specific trouble area.

Comment: The answer tells you how to fix your datasource. I just didn't include a code sample.

Comment: In either case, the amount of dev time sunk into resolving core plot issues is obscene. At this point the correct answer for any CorePlot question should be "don't use CorePlot."